# Apple pay commission rate

Tags: ios, shopify, payment-gateway, payment, applepay

I would like to add the apple pay payment method for the sales I made through my own site. As far as I know, Apple charges 30% commission on in-app purchases. However, what % will my commission rate be because I want to add it as a payment method for my own website?

Comment: Apple Pay is different to In-App purchase.  You will pay a fee to your credit card processor (e.g. Stripe) in accordance with your agreement with them.  They will pay some of this fee to Apple, but you do not need to be concerned about that.

Comment: I need full commission rate %

Comment: As I said, you need to refer to your agreement with your payment processor.  It is nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: But shouldn't apple have a flat commission rate? Who should I contact to find out about this commission rate?

Comment: The rate (for you) is 0%.  The bank/credit card processor pays Apple.  They will also charge you for processing the transaction. How much of that fee goes to Apple is between the bank/processor and Apple.

Comment: This does not appear to be on-topic. If you have questions about Apple's practices you should address them to Apple. Please see the [help] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/apple-pay-fees-vex-credit-card-issuers-11633449317):

> **Currently, banks pay Apple a fee when their cardholders use Apple Pay.** Under the planned new process, the fees wouldn’t apply on automatic recurring payments such as gym memberships and streaming services.

In other words, Apple collects part of the [interchange fee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_fee) and the fees aren't paid by merchants. Most payment providers don't charge merchants additional fees for using Apple Pay, but you would need to consult your own payment provider to determine yours is unusual in this regard.